# Apache Airflow setting docker in docker env not to use 'mount_tmp_dir'

Tags: airflow

When runnnig a docker dag from dockerised Airflow environment it gives me a warning msg:

`{docker.py:269} WARNING - Using remote engine or docker-in-docker and mounting temporary volume from host is not supported. Falling back to 'mount_tmp_dir=False' mode. You can set 'mount_tmp_dir' parameter to False to disable mounting and remove the warning`

I looked at the offical website, for where exactly to set it up, however did not find anything explicitly recommended. I tried within the dag specification file:

```
...
t1 = DockerOperator(
    ...
    params={"mount_tmp_dir": False}, 
    ...
     )
```

As the warning is still visible, I do not think my effort was registered by the airflow backend.

What would be the canonical way to set `mount_tmp_dir` to false?

Comment: Looking at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.html, it looks like `mount_tmp_dir` is an argument for `DockerOperator`.  

`t1 = DockerOperator(..., mount_tmp_dir=False)`.  (I haven't tried it myself though)

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried this obvious one before and it did not work. But now it did. Thank you, post it, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mount_tmp_dir` is one of the arguments of `DockerOperator`, so try this.

```
t1 = DockerOperator(
    ...
    mount_tmp_dir=False
    ...
)
```

Ref: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.html